# Can I view file names from zipped tar file without unzip and extracting it?

Tags: tar, zip

Can I view file names from zipped tar file without unzip and extracting it? The command `tar -tvf` will show the file contents with out extracting it. Is it possible with zipped tar file?

Comment: `tar -tvzf myfile.tgz` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use the command

```
tar -tvzf file.tar.gz
```

The `-z` argument handles zipped tarfiles.

Comment: Thank you it is working. Unfortunately its not working in my AIX flavour but it is working in other flavours of unix